# Listing mixed male and female nouns. Muchos or muchas?

Tags: género, español-neutral

If I'm listing four things, three of which are female, would I say *muchas* or *muchos*?

> Tiene muchos playas, montañas, tiendas y **restaurantes**

If **restaurantes** is male then do I start the sentence with **muchos** even though it's followed by the feminine **playa** ?

Answer (score 9):

If you start with a female one, you start with ***muchas.*** If you start with a male one, you start with ***muchos.***

In your example we have

> Tiene ***muchas*** playas, montañas, tiendas y restaurantes.

Since ***restaurante*** is a male word, it doesn't change the sense of the sentence.

We can do an inversion like:

> Tiene ***muchos*** restaurantes, playas, montañas, y tiendas.

But since there are more females than males, it's better to put first the ones in more quantity.

A more complex result is to have:

> Tiene ***muchas*** playas, restaurantes, montañas y tiendas.

Here you have female, male, female and female. However since the first word was used with its correct genre, the sense of the sentence doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

It would sound better if you had `restaurantes` at the beginning of the list.

> Tiene muchos restaurantes, playas, etc...

Mixed masculine and feminine nouns would evaluate to the masculine, so your sentence is correct, it just sounds odd to have the feminine noun first with a masculine adjective.  It might sound a bit better if you said.

> Tiene muchas playas, montañas, tiendas y muchos restaurantes.

Comment: Perfect thanks. So it's correct, but has less flow/sounds a bit awkward?

Comment: Las recomendaciones que tienes son buenas, pero ten cuidado que la concordancia de determinantes y adjetivos antepuestos se hace con el sustantivo o pronombre más próximo a esos, en tal caso, en la oración original, debe ser «muchas» aunque contemple entes masculinos también.  Véase *DPD* «concordancia» §§ 3.1,3 .

Comment: Nunca he oído de eso, pero gracias por avisarme.